# java.lang.NullPointerException, why?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, google-cloud-endpoints

In my android app which uses google cloud endpoints as a scalable backend solution, I am getting a NullPointerException when making a call to get the users friends in the exposed endpoints api.

Initially, in my fragment, FriendFragment, I make the call to the async task class;

```
new EndpointTask.GetFriends(mUserId, FriendFragment.this).execute();
```

Then, this async task class makes a call to the endpoints api method named getFriends;

```
return mApi.getFriends(mUserId).execute().getItems();
```

This calls this method which functions as expected in the api explorer;

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getFriends", path = "friends", httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET)
    public List<Profile> getFriends(@Named("userId") String userId) {
        Profile profile = ofy().load().key(Key.create(Profile.class, userId)).now();
        if (profile != null) {
            List<Profile> friends = new ArrayList<>(0);
            for (String friendId : profile.getFriendIds()) {
                Profile friend = ofy().load().key(Key.create(Profile.class, friendId)).now();
                friends.add(friend);
            }
            return friends;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The returned List is sent back to the fragment via an interface which it implements;

```
// The interface
public interface OnFetchedFriends {
    void sendFriends(List<Profile> friends);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Profile> friends) {
    super.onPostExecute(friends);
    mListener.sendFriends(friends);
}

// In the fragment
@Override
public void sendFriends(List<Profile> friends) {
    mFriends.clear();
    mFriends.addAll(friends);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This data is then passed into the adapter and should be displayed onscreen in a recycler view;

```
RecyclerView requestRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.friends_recycler_view);
requestRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
requestRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

mAdapter = new FriendAdapter(mFriends);
requestRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.hb.backend.birthpayApi.model.ProfileCollection.getItems()' on a null object reference
    at com.hb.birthpay.utils.EndpointTask$GetFriends.doInBackground(EndpointTask.java:101)
    at com.hb.birthpay.utils.EndpointTask$GetFriends.doInBackground(EndpointTask.java:67)
```

Why is a java.lang.NullPointerException occurring?

Comment: probably `mApi.getFriends(mUserId)` returns an empty set...

Comment: `mApi.getFriends(mUserId).execute()` is returning null.

Comment: Have you tried debugging this to see what is null. Since you have a chain of commans `return mApi.getFriends(mUserId).execute().getItems();` it makes it difficult to see what exactly would be returning null.

Comment: yes the best idea is to split the compound call into pieces and inspect every object. You'll probably find one of them to be `null`

Comment: I will give it a try. @buczek

Comment: I cant seem to figure it out. @weirdgyn

Comment: @TomFinet what do you mean? You're unable to split the command or are unable to backtrack what's null?

Comment: I am unable to backtrack what is null.@weirdgyn

Comment: Clearly, the get friends method in the endpoints api is returning null. @buczek